# Spherical triangle has the sum of interior angles greater than 180

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology, elliptic-curves, geometric-topology

Hi i am looking for an answer for my question that's why i need some help.My question is following:
   Prove/show that what is the sum of interior angle of a triangle in R3? (The triangle is convex)

İ think that the triangle has a positive curvature so that the sum of angles must be greater than 180. But i could not prove this one.Or, is there any way else to prove that? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).